# print index of dataframe using conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have the following code to print out the index or the value of col 2 if col 3 equals some value but I get this result.

```
Float64Index([       0.049829, 0.0498290195124, 0.0498290448177,
              0.0498290758937, 0.0498291127182, 0.0498291552693,
              0.0498292035247, 0.0498292574626, 0.0498293170609,
              0.0498293822977,
              ...
                     0.066077,        0.066077,        0.066077,
                     0.066077,        0.066077,        0.066077,
                     0.066077,        0.066077,        0.066077,
                     0.066077],
             dtype='float64', name=u'tau', length=4706000)

tau_dz = pd.read_csv('m3e9_z100_l320.txt', sep=' ', header=None)
tau_dz.columns = ['lambda', 'zeta', 'tau', 'dz']

#User inputs the values of tau and dz they want cls for
TAU = float(input("Enter the value of tau: "))
DZ = float(input("Enter the value of dz: "))

TAU = min(abs(tau_dz['tau'] - TAU))
print TAU

tau_dz.index = tau_dz['tau'] - TAU
print tau_dz.index
```

Comment: What is happening here `tau_dz.index = tau_dz['tau'] - TAU` ?

Comment: Please follow How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) get better response.